# jQuery expand collapse all DT tags in definition list (DL)

Tags: jquery, html, treeview

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish, except that it uses lists (UL and LI): http://homework.nwsnet.de/news/ea21_turn-nested-lists-into-a-collapsible-tree-with-jquery

My data is structured using DL, DT and DD tags, like this:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Root</dt>
  <dd>
    <dl>
      <dt>Coffee</dt>
      <dd>black hot drink</dd>
      <dt>Milk</dt>
      <dd>white cold drink</dd>
      <dt>Beer</dt>
      <dd>
        <dl>
          <dt>European</dt>
          <dd>Heineken</dd>
          <dt>Mexican</dt>
          <dd>Corona</dd>
        </dl>
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

How can I use jQuery to turn each DT (and its corresponding DD content) into a collapsible/expandable node, ie a treeview?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At it's most basic, you can simply use `toggle` with the `click` event handler to do this:

```
// When any dt element is clicked
$('dt').click(function(e){
    // All dt elements after this dt element until the next dt element
    // Will be hidden or shown depending on it's current visibility
    $(this).nextUntil('dt').toggle();
});

// Hide all dd elements to start with
$('dd').hide();
```

You will, of course, want to use `toggleClass` to add additional styles as appropriately, as well as other effects. See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/EA4R5/1/

Comment: Amazing, just what I was looking for. And thanks for making me aware of jsFiddle!

Answer (score 1):

The man himself John Resig has already a video explaning how to create such menu using DL, DT and DD tags. Check out:

- http://15daysofjquery.com/jquery-online-movie-tutorial-by-john-resig/29/