# How to prevent collapsible content not to expand by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The collapsible content expands by default. But I want to make it expand by click only. How to set up something like, `expand="false"` by default here?

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
       $("#expand dt a").click(function () {
       $(this).parent().siblings("dd").slideToggle(); 
       });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<dl>
  <dt class="right">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/more-button.png">
      <span class="learn">&nbsp;Learn More:Areas of Practise</span>
    </a>
  </dt>

  <!--collapsible content begins-->
  <dd class="row collapse">
    test
  </dd>
  <!--collapsible content ends-->

  </dt>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `style="display: none;"` on `<dd>` for initial value.

> If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown. The display property is saved and restored as needed.

http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Answer (score 0):

Remove class "collapse" from DD or set style="display:none" to DD

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

1. Hide all elements with `$('dd').hide();`
2. When any `'dt'` item is clicked, toggle next item below `'dt'`

Also have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478122/jquery-expand-collapse-all-dt-tags-in-definition-list-dl)

```
// Hide all dd elements to start with
    $('dd').hide();    
// When any dt element is clicked
$('dt').click(function(e){
    // All dt elements after this dt element until the next dt element
    // Will be hidden or shown depending on it's current visibility
    $(this).nextUntil('dt').toggle();
});
```

If you do it this way, you also won't need any CSS classes like `collapse`.